# If I deploy an update of a solution to CRM Online, can I just uninstall it to revert all changes?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

If I deploy an update of a solution to CRM Online, can I just uninstall it to revert all changes?

So I install version 1.0 with a custom entity, which has "First Name" and "Last Name" fields. Then I install version 1.1 with the addition of a "Department" field

If I uninstall version 1.1 ...

- will it revert to version 1.0, leaving just the First Name and Last Name?
- or does it completely uninstall the lot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the solution is managed then uninstalling it will remove all solution components.  If the solution is unmanaged then uninstalling will remove the solution but all components will remain in the default solution.  You would need to remove them manually.

Assuming a managed solution then in your example it will not revert back to 1.0 but will entirely remove that solution.